# Steal the focus from a full screen app in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt

I want to open a Qt file dialog on top and it works setting the Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint flag. The problem is that if there's an application running on full screen my dialog doesn’t get the focus.

How could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try     `m_pModeless->show();
    m_pModeless->activateWindow();
    m_pModeless->raise();
    m_pModeless->setFocus();` ?

Comment: Why do you think you have a right to steal focus from a full-screen app? This is a very user-hostile act.

Comment: @Chernobyl: thank you very much for your answer, it works. The key was raise() method.

Comment: @Andrew Medico: I´m developing an app which has to cooperate with browsers. If a user clicks on our website to upload a file then the dialog must be opened on top. I´m not stealing focus randomly, I´m going to do it because the user expects it.

Comment: @Emilio it's good. I post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dia->show();
dia->activateWindow();
dia->raise();
dia->setFocus()
```